# date + time can't convert to milliseccond

Tags: java

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(sTransDateTime2.substring(0, 4));
int month = (Integer.parseInt(sTransDateTime2.substring(4, 6)) - 1);
int day = Integer.parseInt(sTransDateTime2.substring(6, 8));
int hour = Integer.parseInt(sTransDateTime2.substring(8, 10));
int minute = Integer.parseInt(sTransDateTime2.substring(10, 12));
int second = Integer.parseInt(sTransDateTime2.substring(12));

System.out.println("year=" + year + "| month= " + month + "| day=" + day);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
Calendar calConvert = Calendar.getInstance();
calConvert.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
sTransDateTime2 = Long.toString(calConvert.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
System.out.println("debug date: " + sTransDateTime2);
```

my date time is year=2017| month= 7| day=28| hour= 17| minute=0,
After convert to milliseconds it become 1501232400.
The result of date is correct, will be 28 Jul 2017, but time become 9.00pm. 
Any wrong on my coding?

Thanks

Comment: have you considered using a java library for parsing the date?  e.g. SimpleDateParser?

Comment: One error in you code: the format string is wrong, should be `MM/dd/yyyy` instead of `mm/dd/yyyy`. Note that `mm` means **minutes**, not months. Use `MM` for months. (Actually - why do you have this `SimpleDateFormat` object at all? It isn't even used in your code).

Comment: Perhaps you are using local TimeZone settings in one conversion but not in the other.

Comment: @Jesper, i no using date format...i forgot to commend it...

Answer (score 1):

stop learning the old broken java.date and move into the java.time

```
LocalDateTime myldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 7, 28, 17, 0);
System.out.println(myldt);
System.out.println(myldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

Comment: my server only using java 6.

Comment: LocalDateTime mean will get local time zone? cause may be the time zone is different

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the conversion to milliseconds is being done in one TimeZone, but the system on which the milliseconds are converted to date is in a different timezone. 
`28th July, 2017 17:00:00` gives seconds from epoch as `1501232400` when in `UTC+08:00` timezone, but these seconds from epoch give back `28th July, 2017 21:00:00` in `UTC+12:00` timezone.

To illustrate the above, I have explicitly set the timezone to `UTC+8:00` when calculating the milliseconds. (I have set my system timezone to `UTC+12:00` to show the output)

```
    System.out.println("year=" + year + "| month= " + month + "| day=" + day);
    Calendar calConvert = Calendar.getInstance();
    calConvert.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8:00"));
    calConvert.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);     
    sTransDateTime2 = Long.toString(calConvert.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
    System.out.println("debug date: " + sTransDateTime2);
    System.out.println(new Date(calConvert.getTimeInMillis()));
```

This gives me the output as below:

```
year=2017| month= 6| day=28
debug date: 1501232400
Fri Jul 28 21:00:00 NZST 2017
```

Please note that `Date` always prints the date in local timezone. So, it has converted the milliseconds as per local timezone and the time changes to `21:00`.

Now I format this date to make sure that I get the output back in `UTC+08:00` only, whatever be the system timezone.

```
Date dt = calConvert.getTime();
DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8:00"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(dt));
```

Now I get the output as : `07/28/2017 17:00:00` instead of the earlier date with `21:00` as time.

So, the conclusion is that you need to format the date to be displayed in a specific timezone, if you want to avoid it picking up the default timezone of the system on which it is displayed.

To avoid all the cumbersome code and confusing issues, as suggested in the other answer, go for the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API. `java.time` is available from JDK 8. As you are using JDK 6, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Just to illustrate the ease with which things could be done with `java.time` , the following does the same what your code does , but in a concise and easily understandable way:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(year, month, day), 
                          LocalTime.of(hour, minute,second), ZoneId.of("Asia/Macau"));
long secondsFromEpoch = zdt.toEpochSecond();

//To convert back
ZonedDateTime zdtBack = Instant.ofEpochSecond(secondsFromEpoch)
                               .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Macau"));
System.out.println(zdtBack);
```